# Display certain records in DataGrid in Flash Builder

Tags: mysql, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

I have an application with a `DataGrid` and I have it's Data/Services coming from a `MySQL` database relayed by a `ColdFusion` server. I have a table that has the following columns: `name`, `tstamp`, `store`, and `dept`. Here is my question:

On the click of a button, I want to be able to display the most recent tstamp(as a label) for a name that was selected prior to the button being clicked. This label will change depending on what name the user selects. Ive tried writing MySQL queries in the `.cfc` files and Ive also tried to do it using straight `Flex` code without any luck. Does anyone have any tips they can give me to point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code in the `.cfc` file that is incomplete due to not knowing how to change the results based on the name the user picks.

```
<cffunction name="recent_timestamp" output="false" access="remote" returntype="any" >
    <cfset var qAllItems="">
    <cfquery name="qAllItems" datasource="TimeClock">
        SELECT * FROM tbl_timestamps 
        WHERE tstamp = (select max(tstamp) from tbl_timestamps where store = "Dodge")
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn qAllItems>
</cffunction>
```

I tried to use `Flex` code as well but I can't figure out how to call certain data fields from a `Data Service`.

Comment: Please include samples of what you've tried.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly the issue is not in the query but in the selection of the datagrid row and getting the correct value from there.. true?

Comment: The `DataGrid` itself is invisible because I don't want the user to see the grid, but rather the grid holds the information that I will use to populate the `TimeStampLabel` when the user signs in so they can view their last time stamp. Does that make sense? So the issue itself isn't in the query, its retrieving the correct information based on the users selected name.

Comment: So how does the entry get selected?

Comment: The entry doesn't get selected. Thats the tricky part. Maybe I don't even need a `DataGrid` to accomplish what I'm trying to do here. The `DataGrid` only served as a repository for the data and then I could select certain types of data by using the `timeStampGrid.selectedItem.____` code. Sorry if I am confusing you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22082/discussion-between-ethrbunny-and-green-developer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion the resolution was to get the necc data via join at login time. This issue was bypassed.